# Signing Visual Studio 2013 application with self Signed Certificate

Tags: visual-studio-2013, certificate, certificate-authority

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate to build different VB .Net Applications.

To sign my Software I created a Certificate Authority on a Linux machine first. Using this CA I singed an Intermediate Authority, which i used to sign a Code Signing Certificate.

I then converted my Code Signing Certificate to a pfx file and included the Entire Cert Chain and checkt it on Windows:

```
C:\Windows\System32>certutil -dump C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\codesigning.pfx
Enter PFX password:
================ Certificate 0 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 0:
Serial Number: a3f1a753378e4c2a
Issuer: E=contact@marcsn.de, CN=Marc SN Root CA, OU=Marc SN Certifica
te Authority, O=Marc SN, S=North Rhine-Westphalia, C=DE
 NotBefore: 20.04.2017 20:25
 NotAfter: 10.04.2057 20:25
Subject: E=contact@marcsn.de, CN=Marc SN Root CA, OU=Marc SN Certific
ate Authority, O=Marc SN, S=North Rhine-Westphalia, C=DE
Signature matches Public Key
Root Certificate: Subject matches Issuer
Cert Hash(sha1): 0c 2b 39 fb 9d 25 fa 80 d6 49 a1 80 6a c2 0b 03 19 27 80 33
----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
No key provider information
Encryption test FAILED

================ Certificate 1 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 1:
Serial Number: 1000
Issuer: E=contact@marcsn.de, CN=Marc SN Root CA, OU=Marc SN Certifica
te Authority, O=Marc SN, S=North Rhine-Westphalia, C=DE
 NotBefore: 20.04.2017 20:43
 NotAfter: 05.01.2037 20:43
Subject: E=contact@marcsn.de, CN=Marc SN Intermediate CA, OU=Marc SN
Certificate Authority, O=Marc SN, S=North Rhine-Westphalia, C=DE
Non-root Certificate
Cert Hash(sha1): ef c3 d0 68 35 a7 21 cd 4f a2 c7 a5 1b cc 17 da 11 bd 94 ec
----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
No key provider information
Encryption test FAILED

================ Certificate 2 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 2:
Serial Number: 1000
Issuer: E=contact@marcsn.de, CN=Marc SN Intermediate CA, OU=Marc SN C
ertificate Authority, O=Marc SN, S=North Rhine-Westphalia, C=DE
 NotBefore: 20.04.2017 22:35
 NotAfter: 30.04.2018 22:35
Subject: E=contact@marcsn.de, CN=contact@marcsn.de, OU=Marc SN Softwa
re Development, O=Marc SN, S=North Rhine-Westphalia, C=DE
Non-root Certificate
Cert Hash(sha1): f2 f5 74 bb 1f 1b f2 19 0f 06 f2 ae 52 e4 01 0e 60 a7 25 bf
----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
  Provider = Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0
Encryption test passed
CertUtil: -dump command completed successfully.
```

I also installed the root cert into the Windows Certificate store:

[Certificate Store Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFPEb.png)

In the last step I imported the Certificate into Visual Studio. It prompts for my password and imports the Certificate without any problem. However when I view the Details in Visual Studio the Certification Path only shows my Signing Cert, not my Root Cert and my Intermediate Cert.

When I try to Publish my Application Visual Studio throws the following Error:

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4755,5): error MSB3482: Fehler beim Signieren: A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.
```

I assume this Error happens, because Visual Studio ignores the certchain, that is included in my Certificate (as shown in the certutil output above). Does anyone know how to fix this error?